# Weaker Goldbach's Conjecture: Is every number the sum of two pseudoprimes?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, pseudoprimes

Here, pseudoprimes refer to composite pseudoprimes as well as primes. Can this be easily shown for Fermat Pseudoprimes? For Strong Pseudoprimes? For Pseudoprimes to a constant base? etc.

Comment: I do not think there is hope to prove this weaker version.